# Cocoa:O SX app missing all icons after archived

Tags: xcode, macos, archive

As above,I archived by XCode6.4,my app was work well on my own macbook,but i sent '.app' file to my friends,there was no icon in app.But If I archived by Xcode 7.0 beta5,it worked well.Does anyone help?Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

look at the content of package in your app if there is a App.icns if not, copy them manually...